# Why should we go for one solution with ETL/DWH/BI rather that specialized solution for each of these?

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, etl, difference

I'm working in a reporting service application where I use ETL/DWH/BI using SSIS packages for ETL and SQLserver for Data warehouse my client wants to know why should they would go for one solution with ETL/DWH/BI rather that specialized solution for each of these?

I will pleased for any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Business needs vary, no-one will be able to tell you what you should do for your client without analyzing that clients needs.

However, general reasons for using the SQL Server family of tools include:

- All components are supported by the same vendor (Microsoft).  This can help prevent the finger pointing when you have a problem integrating tools from different vendors.
- In general, compatibility issues are reduced by using a single vendor and feature overlap is less common between tools within a suite.
- Licensing/acquisition is streamlined.  Buying from a single vendor will generally require less overhead than buying from multiple vendors.
- Consolidated technical base.  In my experience, there is a lot of overlap in the skills of an individual professional.  Other than a non-development DBA and entry-level developers, the SQL Server professionals I have worked with generally have at least a functional understanding of the full suite of tools.  I've yet to work with someone that can only produce in a single tool (SSIS, SSRS, etc).  When you have tools from multiple vendors, you will have a harder time finding candidates that already have knowledge of all of your tools.  This may not be an issue if your staffing needs do not force individuals to wear multiple hats or your volume of work in each category (ETL, Reporting, etc) requires dedicated resources.

Some downsides

- Rarely are all of the tools "best of breed".  The tools may be very good, but a focused competitor can generally out perform a suite in some areas.
- Vendor lock-in is even more likely.  If a tool falls behind the curve, it can be much harder to replace when the tool is part of a comprehensive suite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions it helps a lot